# Split string to get hours

Tags: javascript

```
var date = '28/05/2011 12:05';
var elem = date.split('');
hours = elem[0];
```

I have the above date format, please tell me how to split this, so that I can obtain `12` (hours) from this string?

Comment: `''` was the only delimiter you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var date = '28/05/2011 12:05';
var hrs = date.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single call to split each component using a regular expression:

```
var date = '28/05/2011 12:05';
var elem = date.split(/[/ :]/);
alert(elem[3]); //-> 12
```

> **Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9c7/**

Comment: @Marcel: it still uses split, which can accept a Regex as input.  I seriously doubt that speed would be a concern on such a small string, and I don't think that splitting, accessing array index, splitting, accessing array index is a very readable or efficient solution either.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, especially about code readability.

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that actually makes all of the parts of the date and time accessible. (The other answers use split() but throw away all the other pieces, so for those if we're going to go ahead and assume a consistent format why not just use substring() rather than split()?)

Answer (score 1):

A RegEx solution:

```
var myRe = /([0-9]+):[0-9]+$/i;
var myArray = myRe.exec("28/05/2011 12:05");

alert(myArray[1]); // 12
```

Some additional info:

- Working code sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BvFWm/).
- [About RegEx in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's a consistent format:

```
var hours = date.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]
```

is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

when working with Dates it's better to use dedicated date/time functions:

```
var date = '28/05/2011 12:05';
var ms = Date.parse(date)
alert(new Date(ms).getHours())
```

Comment: Internet Explorer won't parse that date.

Comment: After testing, neither will webkit.

Comment: Don't use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse arbitrary date strings; you only should feed it (and the `Date` constructor) strings formatted according to [RFC 1123](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123) or (newer versions of JavaScript engines only) a subset of [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). All the rest is unspecified and thus completely implementation-dependent, resulting in an unexpected cross-browser behaviour.

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with extracting part of a date/time string rather than trying to parse the date and then get the part that you need.  Apart from time-zone conversion and date validation it doesn't necessarily offer any advantage.  There's definitely no advantage in this case.